# Request Entity Too Large issue

Tags: laravel-5, image-uploading, shared-hosting

i have laravel application hosted on godaddy, i have multipe image upoader in form , when using small size images it work fine , but when add only one image of size 1 mb i got "Request Entity Too Large message" i have tied many solution like add php.ini file or even user.ini to public_html folder with this contents

```
file_uploads = On

upload_max_filesize = 256M
post_max_size = 257M

max_input_time = 300
max_execution_time = 300
max_file_uploads = 20
```

for both file but unfortunately still get the same error

Comment: This may be obvious.. but did you restart php after changing php.ini? Otherwise the changes will not take effect

Comment: @PrashanD yes i killed all processes , but nothing changed

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't change the php.ini settings on GoDaddy shared hosting, but give this a try:

```
post_max_size xxM # change xxM to whatever you need
```